# Adding Required Attribute to Inputs in DIV On Radio Button Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am having an issue with a piece of my code on my registration form. Users are about to select account type. (1 and 2) which changes the fields that are required on the form.

I have wrapped the required fields in a div to make it easier to access them, however I'm getting an issue with adding the required attribute to the inputs.

```
function changeAccount(input)
{
    var selected = $(input).data("type");

    if (selected == "1")
    {
        $('#at-1-inputs').slideDown(500);
        $('#at-2-inputs').slideUp(500);

        $('#at-2-inputs').find('input').each(function() 
        {
            $(this).removeAttr('required');
        });
        $('#at-1-inputs').find('input').each(function() 
        {
            $(this).addAttr('required');
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // SAME AS ABOVE IN REVERSE
    }
}
```

But whenever I change the radio button, in my JS console I'm getting a

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I have checked and the function is definitely getting called when the radio buttons are clicked.

Does anyone have any insight on this issue?

Comment: `$(this).prop('required', true/false);` to set required as true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
$(this).addAttr('required');
```

to this:

```
$(this).attr('required', 'required');
```

or

```
$(this).prop('required', true);
```

---

`.addAttr()` is not available in jQuery. Either you should use `.attr()` or `.prop()` to set the attribute/property.

---

```
function changeAccount(input)
{
    var selected = $(input).data("type");

    if (selected == "1")
    {
        $('#at-1-inputs').slideDown(500);
        $('#at-2-inputs').slideUp(500);

        $('#at-2-inputs').find('input').each(function() 
        {
            $(this).prop('required', false); // <----use .prop() instead
        });
        $('#at-1-inputs').find('input').each(function() 
        {
            $(this).prop('required', true); //<-----use .prop() instead
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // SAME AS ABOVE IN REVERSE
    }
}
```